# Create Index - Elastic Search - Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create an index using Elastic Search Java API.

My code is similar to this:

```
String indexName = "clients";
Node node =  new NodeBuilder().clusterName(this.clusterName).client(true).node();
Client client = node.client();

client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(indexName).execute().actionGet(); // It fails here

if (client != null) client.close();
if (node != null) node.close();
```

But every time, I execute that I get this error: http://screencast.com/t/MfnTccwho

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the error into the question properly, not a link to a picture of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like mismatch between elasticsearch client version and elasticsearch server version.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check that jvm versions of the elasticsearch cluster and your client match, it happened to me that my client was 1.7 and elasticsearch was running under openjdk 1.6, throwing that exception.

Once both elasticsearch & java versions match you'll get the "real" exception :)